Laser and excited state linewidths in Rabi oscillations
I want to simulate (numerically if analytically is not possible) the behavior of a 2 level system, when driven by a laser (basically transition probability vs laser frequency for fixed interaction time) accounting for the laser and atomic linewidth (in my case I can assume they are comparable). What is the best way to proceed? Thank you!

The finite atomic line width but narrow laser limit is canonically treated in many quanthm

Including the excited state lifetime should be easy, either by adding i\Gamma to the Hamiltonian or using a density matrix formalism. I am more curious about how to account for the laser linewidth.

Oh yeah I thought I said that in my comment but I didn’t. Im curious about how to model the laser line width also.
